# Is there any method to show id_rsa.pub of user by PHP?

Tags: php, file-permissions

I try to list content of id_rsa.pub of users in my server by PHP, but I found that the id_rsa.pub file is not readable by Apache (`drwx------`).

How can I deal with this problem in PHP except for manually changing permission of .ssh folder?

**---Updated---**

The original reason is that I was asked to list the "**information of ssh keys of users on this server**" by PHP, but now I found it is really not recommended to read from .ssh folder.

Comment: You can't. That's the reason for those permissions. Note that opening up the `.ssh`-folder will render the private key unusable by most SSH servers.

Comment: Do you **REALLY** want to give your webserver account the rights to go rummaging around inside other user's home folders? That is INCREDIBLY insecure...

Comment: Totally agreed with you two. I updated the quesion to make it more clear.

Comment: Meet what requirement?  What exact problem are you trying to solve?  And, the problem you are running into doesn't have anything to do with PHP.  You could run PHP as root if you really wanted to... but you probably don't want to.

Comment: OK. I understand, I will run PHP as root.